# Avro runtime exception Not an array

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have user avsc file

```
{
   "namespace": "example.avro",
   "type": "record",
   "name": "User",
   "fields": [
      {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "id",  "type": "int"},
      {"name": "favorite_color", "type": "string"}
   ]
}
```

I have used maven plugin to generate the java class

I have uploaded the schema into confluent schema registry

when I construct the java object and try to publish it to kafka, it throws the below error

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not an array: {"type":"record","name":"User","namespace":"example.avro","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"id","type":"int"},{"name":"favorite_color","type":"string"}]}
```

Maven plugin version 1.11.1

Comment: Check the configuration of producer. Should use the AvroSerializer and not JsonSerializer.